# Pass parameter as a array's element [Vuejs]

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have vuejs code like below,

```
<div v-for="vl in 3">
  {{ data[subject.vl] }}
</div>
```

I want to display `data[subject.0]`, `data[subject.1]`, `data[subject.2]` and `data[subject.3]`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: share exact object ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass array inside `v-for` directive and use `myarr['subject.'+vl]` to make proper key

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    myarr:{
      "subject.0":"Array 0 value",
      "subject.1":"Array 1 value",
      "subject.2":"Array 2 value",
      "subject.3":"Array 3 value",
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="v1 in [0,1,2,3]">{{myarr['subject.'+v1]}}</div>
</div>
```

share exact object, to get another alternative or better solution.

Comment: I would also guess the data looks like this, but I think it's more likely OP has made a mistake like mixing up dot and bracket notation and that subject is actually the array - but as you say, we need to see the data first. (Maybe it's a little misleading calling your object `myarr`, but that's a very minor note - you've got my point.)

Comment: Great! I'll try this.
Thank you so much.